# dateaxisrender jqplot xticks width is not consistent

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I am plotting a graph using dateaxisrender jqplot in jquery.
Here we give the dates that we have received from the server in x-axis.

graph is plotting fine, but the gap between each xtick is different.

suppose my xtciks dates are: "08-Aug", "10-Aug", "01-Sep", "15-sep" , 25-dec.

The gap between "08-Aug" and "10-Aug" is small. 
And the gap between "10-Aug" and "01-Sep" is large 
And the gap between "15-sep" and 25-dec is even larger.

I think the graph is considering the number of days between the dates giving the width between each.
But in my case it should be equal width.

can some body advise how can I fix this urgently?

I am unable to paste the graph image here.

```
$.jqplot(grphOneID, [grdPoints], YI.getGraphOpts(grdXTcks, YAxisLbl)).replot();

getGraphOpts: function (XTcks, YAxisLbl) {
        /// <summary>Object that holds all the setting's required for Graph generation.</summary>
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
        var optsObj =
            {
                axes: {
                    yaxis: {
                        ticks: m_CompositeReport.stdYLbls,
                        label: YAxisLbl,
                        tickOptions: {
                            formatString: '%d'
                        }
                },
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        label: 'Shop',
                        ticks: XTcks,
                        tickOptions: {
                            formatString: "%m/%d",
                            markSize: 4
                        },
                        numberTicks: 0,
                    }
                },
                seriesColors: m_CompositeReport.stdColors.reverse()
            }
        return optsObj;
    },
```

Note: we cannot use CategoryAxisRender because it plots the xtick between the lines as here: http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/2052/
However we need the dates to be plotted on the lines as here: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/customHighlighterCursorTrendline.html

Comment: anybody out there aplss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your x-axis:

```
xaxis: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
    label: 'Shop',
    ticks: XTcks,
    tickOptions: {
        formatString: "%m/%d",
        markSize: 4
    },
    numberTicks: 0
}
```

And include this file to your code: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js